# How to draw the border of a node using late options

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, nodes, tikz-chains

I want to create a series of rectangles, each with a different shade. The shade varies from white to black. I want to make the white (first) rectangle visible by drawing its border.

My first step is to draw all the rectangles, without any conditional code:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=chroma going below,
              node distance=2mm,
              every node/.style={shape=rectangle,minimum size=1cm},
              ]
    \foreach \n [evaluate=\n as \value using 1-\n*0.125] in {0,...,8}
    {
      \definecolor{tmpc}{Hsb}{0,0,\value}
      \draw node[on chain,fill=tmpc] {};
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I tried to replace the `foreach` code with this:

```
    {
      \definecolor{tmpc}{Hsb}{0,0,\value}
      \draw node[on chain,fill=tmpc] {}
      \ifnum\n=0
        (\tikzlastnode) [late options={draw}] % no effect
        (\tikzlastnode.east) [draw] -- ++(1cm,0) % drawn correctly
      \fi
      ; % ends the path
    }
```

Adding `draw` to the node options directly works. Only the `late options` don't behave like I expect them to do - maybe I'm not understanding something here? I have added code to see if the `ifnum` code is actually executed, and it is indeed.

Is there a class of options that don't work as `late options`?

Comment: This question (or the task it is related to) proceeds at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18850/using-foreach-to-draw-a-chain-with-a-branch

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A slightly different way is described in the following code. Note that you don't really need `xcolor` for this. Two `tikz` pictures are drawn, one using `xcolor`, the other using the basic commands in `tikz`. I drew the chain horizontally to save on space. I also added a macro that let's you change the number of nodes.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}


\begin{document}

%with xcolor
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=chroma going right,
    node distance = 2mm,
    every node/.style ={shape=rectangle,minimum size =1cm,on chain}]

\pgfmathsetmacro{\nbnodes}{8}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\factor}{1/\nbnodes}

\foreach \n [evaluate=\n as \value using 1-\factor*\n] in {0,...,\nbnodes}{

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\bordershade}{ifthenelse(\n==0,100,0)}

    \definecolor{tmpc}{Hsb}{0,0,\value}
    \node[draw=black!\bordershade,fill=tmpc] {};
}
\end{tikzpicture}


%without xcolor
\begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=chroma going right,
    node distance = 2mm,
    every node/.style ={shape=rectangle,minimum size =1cm,on chain}]

\pgfmathsetmacro{\nbnodes}{8}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\factor}{100/\nbnodes}

\foreach \n [evaluate=\n as \shade using \factor*\n] in {0,...,\nbnodes}{

    \pgfmathsetmacro{\bordershade}{ifthenelse(\n==0,100,0)}

    \node[draw=black!\bordershade,fill=black!\shade] {};
}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The output is

[image: shading]

Comment: Thanks for the pgfsetmacro example, this way I don't need two nearly equal node commands and don't need to draw a rectangle later. I'll stick with xcolor, though, because I want to specify colors in the Hsv model later.

Answer (score 4):

I believe the `draw` option won't work as a `late` option: The `pgfmanual` says:

> Most of these options will have no effect since you
>   cannot change the appearance of the node

This means things like `fill`, `draw`, `red`, `opacity` etc. won't have an effect, while things like `label`, `alias`, `on chain` etc. will.

To achieve your desired result, I would just draw a rectangle around the node, instead of using the `draw` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[rgb]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[start chain=chroma going below,
              node distance=2mm,
              every node/.style={shape=rectangle,minimum size=1cm},
              ]
    \foreach \n [evaluate=\n as \value using 1-\n*0.125] in {0,...,8}
    {
      \definecolor{tmpc}{Hsb}{0,0,\value}
      \draw node[on chain,fill=tmpc] {}
      \ifnum\n=0
        (\tikzlastnode.north east) rectangle (\tikzlastnode.south west)
      \fi
      ; % ends the path
    }

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: coloured rectangles]

Comment: +1 But you need to compensate for the `outer sep` I believe. The anchors do not lie on the normal node border but `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer xsep}` or `\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/outer ysep}` away from them (usually `.5\pgflinewidth`) so that arrows to the node stop at the line not in the middle of the line. Setting `outer sep=0pt` for the node in the first place would make things much easier.

Comment: Your reference to the manual is a good hint. However, I accepted Frédéric's answer, because it works on the node and does not add a rectangle later.