# How do I debug the message “Argument of \XC@definec@lor has an extra }”

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, color

Can anyone provide me with some intuition about what might cause an error like this?

```
Argument of \XC@definec@lor has an extra }
```

I am unable to produce an MWE that demonstrates the error, as it occurs in a large document and when I extract the part that seems to be causing the error and compile it by itself it works as expected and does not produce the error.

I think that it is related to a TikZ picture I am trying to draw.

*Reference: [How to paramerize a tikz chain picture with list of nodes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/99528/16595)*

Comment: Looks like somewhere in your picture you have a typo such as a missing comma as in `fill=redcircle`.

Comment: Is it possible that some other macro or something defined in another package could cause something like this to happen? As exactly the same text seems to work when I put it in a document by itself.

Comment: Also possible. This error usually pops up when the color name is replaced by a number or something incompatible. So maybe a macro which holds the color name is being overwritten by a number etc.

Comment: OK, I have tracked it down to "\usepackage{syntax}" - do you know how I might be able to correct something like this? Does it mean that the syntax package is incompatible with tikz in some way?

Comment: I don't know the syntax package though looks quite old (1996). As far as I can see you can use TikZ for that directly. The fourth tutorial *Putting a Diagram in chains* in the manual seems to replicate the functionality. Without an example it's really difficult to say more.

Comment: The `XC@` prefix suggests a problem with `xcolor`, rather than TikZ

Comment: Narrow... but would solve my problem... :-(